# Would having data with different values coming from different sources but having the same timestamp affect the training of my LSTM model?

Tags: neural-network, regression, lstm, data-cleaning, preprocessing

If I have two readings of the same data as follows

```
timestamp         concentration1 concentration2
2016-01-01 01:00  30.4           10
2016-01-01 01:00  36.4           16
```

Would this somehow impact the training of model negatively or confuse it in some sense or does the model know that these readings are from two difference sources?

If it does affect it would I then create a new feature that specifies where a concentration comes from as one of the two following ways?

1-

```
timestamp         concentration 1-A       concentration 2-A      concentration 1-B      concentration 2-B 
2016-01-01 01:00  30.4                    10                     36.4                    16
```

2-

```
  timestamp         concentration1 concentration2  source
  2016-01-01 01:00  30.4           10              A
  2016-01-01 01:00  36.4           16              B
```